# Django template blocks not appearing in correct place in rendered template - resulting in jQuery "$ is not defined" error

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-templates

I am using Django 3.2

This is my base template (snippet):

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content={% block page_description %}""{% endblock page_description %}>
    <meta name="keywords" content={% block page_keywords %}""{% endblock page_keywords %}>

    <link rel='icon' href='{% static "img/favicon.ico" %}' type='image/x-icon'/ >     

    <title>{% block page_title %}Demo{% endblock page_title %}</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-SfTiTlX6kk+qitfevl/7LibUOeJWlt9rbyDn92a1DqWOw9vWG2MFoays0sgObmWazO5BQPiFucnnEAjpAB+/Sw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A400%2C300%2C500%2C600%2C700%7CPlayfair+Display%7CRoboto%7CRaleway%7CSpectral%7CRubik">
      
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/footer.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/header.css' %}">

    {% block head_styles %}
    {% endblock head_styles %}  

    {% block head_js %}
    {% endblock head_js %}   

  </head>

  <body>
    {% block header %}
    {% include "partials/header.html" %}
    {% endblock header %}

    {% block messages %}
    {% include 'partials/messages.html' %}
    {% endblock messages %}    


    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="d-flex flex-column sticky-footer-wrapper">

      {% block content %}  
      
      {% endblock content %}   

    </div>    
 

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha512-/DXTXr6nQodMUiq+IUJYCt2PPOUjrHJ9wFrqpJ3XkgPNOZVfMok7cRw6CSxyCQxXn6ozlESsSh1/sMCTF1rL/g==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <!-- Site footer -->
    {% block footer %}
    {% include 'partials/footer.html' %}
    {% endblock footer %}

    {% block body_js %}
    {% endblock body_js %}    

    <script>
      $().ready(function() {

      });
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

#### /path/to/header.html

```
{% load static %}


<!-- Header -->
<header id="js-header" class="u-header u-header--static">
    <!-- ... # snipped -->
    <form  action="/action_page.php" method="GET">
      <button id="btn-submit-item" type="submit" class="btn" style="margin-right: 10px;border: 1px solid #CACACA;">Submit</button>  
    </form>


      {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
      <a class="btn btn-success btn" href="#" role="button">Sign In</a>
      {% else %}
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">{{ user.username }}</a>
      {% endif %}
      </ul>      
        </div>
        <!-- End Navigation -->

      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- End Header -->


{% block body_js %}
<script>
$().ready(function(){
  $( "#btn-submit-item" ).click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
  });
});
</script>
{% endblock body_js %}
```

In rendered page HTML, I get something like this:

```
# ...
<!-- End Header -->



<script>
$().ready(function(){
  $( "#btn-submit-photo" ).click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
  });
});
</script>

# ...

    </div>    
 

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha512-/DXTXr6nQodMUiq+IUJYCt2PPOUjrHJ9wFrqpJ3XkgPNOZVfMok7cRw6CSxyCQxXn6ozlESsSh1/sMCTF1rL/g==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <!-- Site footer -->
```

The placement is in the wrong place - so the JQuery operator `$` is attempting to be used - **BEFORE** the JQuery library is loaded - hence the error.

My question is - why is Django rendering the block in the wrong place - and how do I fix this error?

Comment: included templates are rendered separately (See the note in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include (you would need to scroll down a little bit)), i.e. they won't fill the blocks of the including template. You would need to move that script tag to your base template, or make that as another template that can be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're rendering header.html in `{% block header %}` which is added before the jquery script. Therefore, $ is undefined.

**Solution 1:**

Move the jquery include to the `<head></head>` of your html, like you did with the bootstrap.min.css file.

**Solution 2:**

If you want to have your jquery loaded just before the body closing tag (`</body>`), you should move your inline jquery to a .js file and include that after including jQuery. For example:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-/DXTXr6nQodMUiq+IUJYCt2PPOUjrHJ9wFrqpJ3XkgPNOZVfMok7cRw6CSxyCQxXn6ozlESsSh1/sMCTF1rL/g=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="your_script.js"></script>

</body>
```

Read more about django and static files here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing that - but I'd rather not (if there's another way) - since I don't want to slow down loading of the page.

Having said that, since I'm using CDN, perhaps it's less on an issue - still, waiting to hear more from those with more experience in this area.